# Getting actual size of a file in Java?

Tags: java, file

I stuck into a problem.

1. I started downloading a file from torrent. the Total Size of the
   File is 699 MB.
2. But after a minute i stop my torrent client, torrent client shows 7
   MB of data has been downloaded, I have only 1 File in Queue.
3. Using Java IO function i calculated length of file and it show 699 MB of Size

File file= new File("D:/Easy.A.2010.BDRip.XviD-iMBT/easy.a.2010.bdrip.xvid-imbt.avi");

```
System.out.println("File Size="+file.length());
```

// After converting to MBs i got it is 699 MB

at later phase i am splitting file into different equal size parts and uploading to server. as the file size is not actual size of the file so i got Exception

```
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
```

Please tell me how can i get actual size of the file, or get information about the file that it is complete file or not.

Thanks

Comment: All the size part is understandable but we need to see code where you get the exception as that is nothing to so with file size

Comment: When you are creating an Array check what value you are using? Can we see some related part of your code

Comment: I guess you are doing something like 
String[] negative = new String[-1]; where "-1" could be a value of your variable you are using to instantiate your array

Comment: I am not sure about Torrent, but when you started downloading a file emule created a file with the final size (probably all of 0s) and later it was replacing the contents of the file with the downloaded data. Have you checked the actual file in the OS?

Comment: I simply want to check the actual size of the file, or the size of the data that is contained by that file.

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes i checke it on OS, and on OS it is 699 MB, while the data downloaded was only 7 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is relevant, but all the torrent clients I have used create files of the final size at the beginning of the download.

i.e for the 699 MB movie, a blank 699 MB file is created right at the start, and the 7 MB downloaded only means that 7 MB from those blanks has been filled in, but the file size on disk remains 699 MB all throughout the download.

Comment: yes you are right. , I only want a solution, that my program should show 7MB size of that file.

Comment: @amal I mean a file that occupies 699 MB of space on disk, but contains garbage/random data.

Comment: @amal: yes a blank 699 MB file

Comment: @Asghar I'm sorry I do not know how to do that. The only feasible way might be to query the torrent client itself.

Comment: @Asghar , check the implementation of the torrent you are using . Maybe it stores that data in a separate file . What you are printing out is the size of the file as known to the OS . And of course , you can examine the contents of the file to see if you can distinguish the actual downloaded data from the filler data , though i doubt that is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Angit is right, torrent client crates blank file with size = torrent_file and if you download 7MB then it fills the blank file with that and if you want to calculate first check to see if file that torrent client creates is filled with blank then you can calculate how much blanks or non blanks you have and after that is easy :).

Answer (score 1):

Make up your mind. Is your question about file sizes or the NegativeArraySizeException? File.length() gives you the length of the file as per the last time the directory was updated. If the file is still open and still being extended this information may not be current.

Comment: my question is just about the actual size of the file. i mean which is 7MB